# How does this line work: obj['e'+type+fn] = fn

Tags: javascript, event-handling, helper

I have been looking everywhere for an explanation on this. I know that, in Javascript, you can get/set properties to objects using square bracket notation, but what is going on when you use '+' in brackets, like this:

```
obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
```

I found this code in the Javascript & Jquery book by Jon Duckett. He was using this code as a helper function, originally created by John Resig.

Here's the full block of code.

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
   if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
      obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
      obj[type+fn] = function(){
                        obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );
                     }
      obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
   } else {
      obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
   }
};
```

When I put it together, this is what I see (which doesn't make sense to me):

```
var obj = {
    e: fn,
    type: fn,
    fn: fn
};
```

Comment: `+` concatenates strings, that's it, whether it is in brackets or not does not make a difference. `+` will call `toString` if necessary.

Comment: This code is rather ugly. I assume its workings are not explained in that book; you should avoid using it. Nowadays, these kind of `addEvent` helper methods are simply archaic.

Comment: Do you have any modern alternatives to recommend for this? I assume you're referring to using jquery, but perhaps you had something else in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> but what is going on when you use '+' in brackets

It's an expression, just as everything else in [property brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). In this case, it concatenates the string `"e"` with the type of the event and the [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) listener function, to get a fairly unique property name.

Comment: Wow, I just got it. The book did say that it was trying to create a unique property name, but for some reason, I was thinking that it was doing something more advanced.    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;  means obj.etypefn = fn

Comment: Nah, it means something like `obj["eclickfunction(){alert(\"Hi\");}"] = fn;` which is not even accessible via dot notation :-)